# Web Reference works, but A Service Reference complains about Soap version

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, asmx, service-reference, web-reference

I have to connect to a legacy web service.

In visual studio, if I do a Add Service Reference, then enter the url of the WSDL file on server. My service shows up, and I write the code against it. But when I run the code I get this error:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The envelope version of
>   the incoming message (Soap12
>   (http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope)) does not match that of the
>   encoder (Soap11 (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/)). Make
>   sure the binding is configured with the same version as the expected
>   messages.

My app.config looks like this:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="LoginServiceSoap" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://server/Service.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="LoginServiceSoap" contract="Stuff.Login.LoginServiceSoap"
                name="LoginServiceSoap" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

However, I am able to communicate with the service fine, if I add a 'Web Reference'. But my understanding is that I am supposed to use Service References now, instead of WebReferences. I am assuming I have something wrong in my above config.

Or am I forced to use a Web Reference, because of the type of service I am connecting to?

Comment: "Make sure the binding is configured with the same version as the expected messages."

Comment: John Saunders, sorry to be dense, but not sure how to do what you are asking?

Comment: Ended up just using Web references, as they work for now.

Answer (score 1):

Sheamus,

You could (theoretically) add the version number to the binding definition.

```
envelopeVersion="None/Soap11/Soap12"
```

With, of course, the right value for your service.

So it would look more like:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="LoginServiceSoap"
             envelopeVersion="Soap12" />
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Hope this helps you do things your way.

Comment: I have the same problem. When i try adding  'envelopeVersion="Soap12"' , i get a error: 'the "envelopeVersion"attribute is not allowed'.