# WCF - Service Reference failed LogIn because soap version

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

When i try login to WCF, i get the error message:

```
An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The envelope version of the incoming message (Soap12 (http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope))
does not match that of the encoder (Soap11 (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/)).
Make sure the binding is configured with the same version as the expected messages.
```

I tried to solve it as recomended 
[as answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396885/web-reference-works-but-a-service-reference-complains-about-soap-version/26638067#comment58390571_26638067eference-works-but-a-service-reference-complains-about-soap-version/26638067#comment58390571_26638067)

by replacing:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="LoginServiceSoap" />
</basicHttpBinding>
```

with:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
   <binding name="LoginServiceSoap"
         envelopeVersion="Soap12" />
</basicHttpBinding>
```

but i get a error:

```
the "envelopeVersion"attribute is not allowed
```

Thanks.

Comment: Switch from `basicHttpBinding` (which is SOAP 1.1) to `wsHttpBinding` (which is SOAP 1.2), or use a custom binding.

Answer (score 0):

`basicHttpBinding` is SOAP 1.1.  The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361(v=vs.110).aspx) states that for this binding for the `envelopeVersion` the only valid value is "Soap11".

`wsHttpBinding` is SOAP 1.2.  Try using that instead of `basicHttpBinding`:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name="LoginServiceSoap" />
</wsHttpBinding>
```